Как заблокировать места на обычном изображении так, чтобы нельзя было выйти за эти границы?
Делаю итоговый проект. По задумке, это хоррор игра. Будет перс и злодей. У меня есть изображение с комнатами, показанными сверху в 2д. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы персонаж и злодей не могли выходить за пределы изображения и стен комнат

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Границы и стены должны быть третьим объектом.
Соответственно на изображении границы и стены
должны быть определённого цвета и это надо использовать для
инициализации третьего объекта.

Измените цвет границ и стен на пару тонов.
Человеческий глаз этого не заметит,
а программно Вы сможете определить границы третьего (статичного объекта).
Останется только прописать взаимодействие персов со стенами.
